# Is a principal bundle over a discrete base space necessarily trivial?

Tags: general-topology, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a topological space with discrete topology. More concretely, one can think of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Then, is it true that any principal $G-$bundle over $X$ is trivial? Here $G$ is an arbitrary Lie group.

I feel this way because every one-point set is open in $X$ but cannot prove rigorously myself.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: There ought to be a site badge for "Question attracting two plausible but contradictory answers". (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bundle is trivial if and only if it has a global section. Take any set theoretic section of the bundle. Since the base is discrete, it will be continuous. So we have
$$s\colon X \to P$$
continuous, such that
$$p\circ s = \mathbb{1}_X$$
The isomorphism of the trivial bundle with the our bundle is given by the map
$$(x,g) \mapsto (x, s(x) \cdot g)$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider an extension of groups $1\rightarrow H\rightarrow G\rightarrow K\rightarrow 1$. where $H,G,K$ are finite. It is a principal bundle over $K$ with typical fiber $H$. If the extension is not trivial the bundle is not trivial.

Comment: Why does it follow that the bundle is nontrivial if the extension is? Of course the extension does not split in the category of groups, but this is not the same as $G$ being a trivial $H$-bundle (case in point, consider the sequence $SU_2\rightarrow U_2\rightarrow S^1$)